# Select não deixa selecionar a opção

Tags: javascript, react, react-hooks

Olá, eu tenho uma lista de `option` de um `select` e não consigo selecionar um item da lista.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

export default function ListCompany(props) {

const Label = styled.label"
display: flex;
align-items: center;
padding: .375rem .75rem;
margin-bottom: 0;
font-size: 1rem;
font-weight: 400;
line-height: 1.5;
color: #495057;
white-space: nowrap;
background-color: #e9ecef;
border: 1px solid #ced4da;
border-radius: .25rem;
border-top-right-radius: 0;
border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
text-align: center!important;
"

const Select = styled.select"
  display: block;
width: 100%;
height: calc(1.5em + .75rem + 2px);
padding: .375rem .75rem;
font-size: 1rem;
font-weight: 400;
line-height: 1.5;
color: #495057;
background-color: #fff;
background-clip: padding-box;
border: 1px solid #ced4da;
border-radius: .25rem;
border-top-left-radius: 0;
border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
transition: border-color .15s ease-in-out,box-shadow .15s ease-in-out;
position: relative;
flex: 1 1 auto;
width: 1%;
margin-bottom: 0;
 "

const [company, setCompany] = useState([]);

useEffect(async () => {
 const response = await fetch('http://localhost:57248/api/listaempresas');
const data = await response.json();

setCompany(data);
}, []);

return (
<div className="input-group mb-3">
  <div className="input-group-prepend">
    <Label htmlFor={props.id} >{props.texto}</Label>
  </div>
  <Select className="" id={props.id} required="required" onChange={props.change}>
    <option value={0}>Escolha...</option>
    {company.map(function (empresa) {
      return (<option key={empresa.ax_cod_empresa} value={empresa.ax_cod_empresa}>{empresa.ax_desc_empresa}</option>);
    })
    }
  </Select>
</div>
  )
}
```

Este seria o Select que é renderizado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ele deixa eu ver as opções porém não deixa selecionar. Quando eu clico ele volta para o `Escolha...`

Como solicitado aqui está o resto do código:

```
<ListCompany
 id="empresa"
 texto="Empresa: "
 change={this.handleCompanyChange}
 errorText={this.state.companyError}
/>
```

Este é o `handleCompanyChange`:

```
handleCompanyChange(e) {
 var g = document.getElementById("empresa");
 var result = g.options[g.selectedIndex].value;
 this.setState({ empresa: result });
}
```

Comment: Gabriel, sua função onChange tá vindo de um componente acima desse (props.change), então precisa exibir ela pra entender o que tá rolando. E o mais importante ali é que está faltando o Value para o Select que possivelmente deve vir por props tbm.

Comment: Como solicitado, já coloquei os trechos correspondentes a chamada da função e ao change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gabriel, acredito que você poderia fazer de forma diferente usando melhor a api do React. Eu faria o seguinte:
Onde tem sua função **handleCompanyChange**:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import ListCompany from './ListCompany'
export default function SeuComponente() {
  const [company, setCompany] = useState([]);
  const [value, setValue] = useState(null);

  useEffect(async () => {
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:57248/api/listaempresas');
    const data = await response.json();
    setCompany(data);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
    {/* Deve ter alguma coisa aqui pra exibir... */}
    <ListCompany
       id="empresa"
       texto="Empresa: "
       change={(e) => setValue(e)}
       value={value}
       companies={company}
       errorText={'sua validação de erro...'}
    />
    </div>
  );

}
```

**No componente ListCompany ficaria algo assim:**

```js
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

// Seus styles devem vir antes de declarar a função para
// evitar renderização das variáveis desnecessariamente.

const SeuEstiloVemAqui = styled.label``; // use 'crase' ao invés de aspas

export default function ListCompany(props) {

return (
<div className="input-group mb-3">
  <div className="input-group-prepend">
    <Label htmlFor={props.id} >{props.texto}</Label>
  </div>
  <Select
    className=""
    id={props.id}
    required="required"
    onChange={(e) => props.change(e.target.value)}
    value={props.value}
    >
      <option value={0}>Escolha...</option>
        {props.companies.map(empresa => (
          <option
            key={empresa.ax_cod_empresa}
            value={empresa.ax_cod_empresa}
          >
            {empresa.ax_desc_empresa}
          </option>
        ))}
  </Select>
</div>
  )
}
```

Teria só que ver como seu Select recebe os valores. Esse parece ser um Select estilizado de alguma lib e alguns recebem o value como objeto `{label: '', value: ''}`

Answer (score 0):

Aqui tem um exemplo de Select que eu utilizo:

```js
 class Teste extends Component {
 
  state = {
    assunto: "",
  };
 
 alterar = e => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };
 
 render() {
  const { ocorrencias } = this.props;
  return (
  <div>
  <select id="assunto" name="assunto" className="form-control"  onChange={this.alterar}>
                  <option value="0">Selecione...</option>
                  {ocorrencias.assunto.map(assunto => (
                   <option value={assunto.codigo}>{assunto.titulo}</option>
                  ))}
                </select>
   </div> 
 )
} 

}
```